# Why enter again (or at the very least confirm) my email address when I click "Forgot password"?

Tags: web, password, password-reminder

In most, if not all, web forms for logging into a site, you have your forgot password link. When clicking the link, you get a new form (usually in a new page) either empty (!) or prefilled with the email address you put in the login form, where you have to click again to actually get the site to send the reset password link.

Is this sane from an UX point of view?

I think it's not and what should happen is that when clicking over the forgot password link, a reset password link is automatically sent. Then the link text changes to "Reset password link sent to xx@yy.zz" until you enter again a wrong password.

Is this worse in any way than the standard procedure?

Similar to [Are we stuck with the "Forgot password" link?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/43602/are-we-stuck-with-the-forgot-password-link) but not exactly the same, as I'm not trying to get rid of the forgot password link, just trying to get rid of the confirmation step.

PS: The security side of the question's here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/97334/why-enter-again-or-at-the-very-least-confirm-my-email-address-when-i-click-fo

PS2: I'm thinking about sites where your username is your email address

Comment: Possible duplicate of:
http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/83006/redundant-enter-user-id-again-for-forgot-password/83007#83007

Answer (score 1):

This is a good improvisation that could be done in the UX. It is certainly not necessary to ask the user the email again.

Addressing the question of security, I am certain not many sites simply display the email address on entering the username(when clicking on forgot password). As an alternative, you could display only a "partial address"(like xyz****@abc.com). I believe sites like "www.envato.com" take a similar approach.

Since this question specifically states that the username is the email address, it is safe to say that this can be done.